# How many degrees of freedom does a photon have in 2+1D?

Tags: electromagnetism, group-theory, parity, degrees-of-freedom, helicity

Wigner's classification of particles implies that the internal degrees of freedom of a particle transform under unitary representations of the subgroup of the Lorentz group that leaves its momentum invariant. In 3+1D for massless particles this group is ISO(2); we typically restrict our attention to representations that transform trivially under the translations of ISO(2) and nontrivially under rotations about the direction of propagation of the particle, which gives us its two helicity states (if one assumes parity is a symmetry of the theory).

In 2+1D the little group of a massless particle is trivial. Therefore we would naively conclude that the only degree of freedom of a massless particle is its momentum, and that there is no internal state analogous to helicity. However, in the standard classical argument for why there are two degrees of freedom in 3+1D (see [Gauge theory and eliminating unphysical degrees of freedom](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/356943/)), one finds that the redundancies of the theory lead us to subtracting two degrees of freedom from the initial total of four to give the two "physical" degrees of freedom associated to the helicity states. It doesn't appear to me naively that there is anything that would be different about the argument in 2+1D, which would lead me to conclude that EM waves in 2+1D should have 3-2 = 1 internal degrees of freedom, even though the little group analysis suggests that there are zero.

My question is -- how do these two pictures square with each other? How many degrees of freedom does the photon truly have in 2+1D?

Comment: The massless little group in D = 2+1 is $\mathbb{Z}_2$ (actually it's $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{Z}_2$, but the $\mathbb{R}$ is usually represented trivially, i.e. continuous spin reps are ignored). There are only two inequivalent irreps of $\mathbb{Z}_2$, and this is interpreted as meaning that there are only two types of spin: 'spin-0 or scalar' (the trivial rep) and spin-1/2 (the other one). So there is no spin 1 in D  = 2+1. Nevertheless, we can still ask whats dynamical content of the Maxwell action. You would find that there is a single degree of freedom, and it is the scalar rep.

Comment: You could also ask what the dynamical content of the Chern-Simons action for a vector field is, i.e. $\mathcal{L} \propto \varepsilon^{abc}A_a\partial_bA_c$, with gauge symmetry $\delta A_a = \partial_a \lambda$. The answer is that in this case there is no degrees of freedom.

Comment: I think this is just a trivial counting issue. In 3+1 dimensions, the gauge redundancy argument says photons have $4 - 2 = 2$ internal degrees of freedom, i.e. there are $2$ photon modes for each photon momentum. A scalar has $1$ internal degree of freedom, i.e. there is $1$ mode for each momentum. That's what we expect for the photon in 2+1 dimensions, by your first argument, and indeed it's true because $3 - 2 = 1$. If you had gotten $0$ instead, that would not be a scalar field, that would be a totally nondynamical field.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're replying to my comment @Knzhou, but if you take a look at Binegar's paper "Relativistic field theories in three dimensions", he mentions at the end that there is a single degree of freedom for the massless vector field (with EoMs coming from Maxwell action), and it is a scalar excitation.

Comment: @NormalsNotFar No, I'm agreeing with your comment. OP's real misconception is that they think a scalar particle should have $0$ degrees of freedom.